# Using jquery to get attribute value for multiple elements. Then use them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
  <span class="thumbnav" id="?"><?php get_the_image(); ?></span>
  <span class="thumbnav" id="?"><?php get_the_image(); ?></span>

  <div class="?" style="display:none;">
       Some image, and a bit of text are staring at you.
  </div>

  <div class="?" style="display:none;">
       Some image, and a bit of text are staring at you.
  </div>
```

My goal is to use jQuery to find the ID value for every <**span**>, then use that ID to set a **.click()** event that will trigger a .**show()** function on the <**div**> elements.

So far I have this:

```
var clasid = $(".thumbnav").attr("id");

 $("#" + clasid).click(function () {
 $("." + clasid).show();
});
```

Which works, but only for the first <**span**>.

So I was wondering if there is a way to make this script work for all the spans, I read the jQuery documentation and they suggest using either **.map()** or **.each()**, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Also it would be great if anyone could give me a hint on how to hide a <**div**> that was active when a new <**div**> is being displayed.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because you cannot have same id for multiple elements. Id must be unique. Use classes instead for the purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write class event and dynamically access that element id:

```
$(".thumbnav").click(function(){

$("." + this.id).show(); // this.id will give you clicked element id

})
```

See [**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xLEvu/)

Comment: Brilliant! So basically 'this' selects the current object? Sorry for being so ignorant, novice here.

Comment: yes you are right $(this) will give you jquery object and this will give you javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can simply bind them using:

```
$(".thumbnav").click(function () {
 $('.'+this.id).show();
});
```